# Can I buy Steam Game Keys on Steam?

Tags: steam

I've recently been on some stream where the streamer pasted some game keys in the chat and the viewers could copy them and redeem them if they were fast enough.
That was pretty cool, however, here's my question:

Can I buy Steam Game Keys on Steam (and not some shady keystore, actual steam!) to give them away to random people on the internet. Buying it as a gift "Send via email" and pasting the link isn't a valid option, since the link only works for an account that's linked to that email adress. (right?)

Comment: Using the gifting options available to you on Steam at checkout should suffice. And it doesn't matter if they have their email linked, they just need the link.

Comment: are you 100% sure that the link will work on any account? After all there's a reciever code attached (looks like this: [LinkToGift]?redeemer=email@adress.com)
After all I don't want to buy games that I then can't give away. I need to be 100% certain on this.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, hence why this is a comment. You'll need to wait for someone else to confirm it then.

Comment: Is this question related at all? [Can I buy games from Steam as Steam Codes?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/278187/145980)

Comment: @MageXy yes, in fact they ask for the same thing but worded it differently...

Comment: @PiotrKowalski I thought so. I wonder why that one is so massively downvoted while this one has a decent, positive score.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. You, as normal user and not game developer, can't buy keys from Steam. But you can achieve the same with Steam gifts:

1. Buy game as a gift.
2. Send it to your e-mail address.
3. Copy activation URL (Just `https://store.steampowered.com/account/ackgift/<some numbers and letters>`, completely omit `redeemer=<e-mail address>`).
4. Send it to someone.

Just tested it so it works for sure.

Comment: As per [this announcement](https://steamcommunity.com/games/593110/announcements/detail/1301948399254001159), using gifts this way is no longer possible.